# Mongoose throws error ECONNREFUSED on Apollo-Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I am sorry if this question is stupid or dumb, please just point me in the right direction, every bit of help is greatly appreciated.

I am currently building a **Apollo-Server** using **express** and **mongoose**. I got the server running with **GraphQ**L, but after connecting it with **mongoose**, which looks like this:

```js
const express = require("express");
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require("apollo-server-express");
const fs = require("fs");

const port = 4000;
const path = "/graphql";

const app = express();

const typeDefs = gql(fs.readFileSync("./schema.graphql", { encoding: "utf8" }));

const resolvers = require("./resolvers");

const mongo = require('./config');
const { User } = require('./models');

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app, path });

app.listen(port, () => console.info(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

with this as my config:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/graphql';
const options = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useCreateIndex: true,
};

//mongoose.connect(url, options);
//mongoose.connection.once('open', () => console.log("Connected to mongoDB at ${url}"));

var connectWithRetry = function () {
  return mongoose.connect(url, options, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(
        "Failed to connect to mongo on startup - retrying in 5 sec\n\n",
        err
      );
      setTimeout(connectWithRetry, 5000);
    }
    mongoose.connection.once("open", () =>
      console.log(`Connected to mongo at ${Constants.mongodbUrl}`)
    );
  });
};

connectWithRetry();
```

This is supposed to work right?
But when i call `npm start server.js` i get the following error:

```
npm start server.js

> start
> node server.js "server.js"

Server started on port 4000
Failed to connect to mongo on startup - retrying in 5 sec MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/myUsername/newServer/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:832:32)
    at /Users/myUsername/newServer/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:345:10
    at promiseOrCallback (/Users/myUsername/newServer/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:9:12)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/Users/myUsername/newServer/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1135:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/myUsername/newServer/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:344:20)
    at connectWithRetry (/Users/myUsername/newServer/server/config.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myUsername/newServer/server/config.js:30:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myUsername/newServer/server/server.js:14:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
```

If you need my installed npm-packages:

```
graphql-node-server@ /path/server
├── apollo-server@2.19.1
├── express@4.17.1
├── graphql@15.4.0
├── mongodb@3.6.3
├── mongoose@5.11.11
└── nodemon@2.0.7
```

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Make sure that Mongodb is running on your local computer because that looks the only case.

Comment: That was one of my questions i did not write ... how do i?

Comment: Oh my god, that is embarrassing, i thought mongoose would start the process for me. If you want to manually answer it, i would gladly give you the correct answer

Comment: Yes you need to start the service. I did check it from my end it was working fine for me with your code.

Comment: Yeah, it does that from time to time, i looked up the command to start the mongoldb process, i works perfectly fine.

Comment: The `open` event is triggering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the MongoDB service before running your code. If it is not running then it will be on a continuous loop trying to reconnect.

Also when it is connected the `open` event will not be triggered. You need to move it outside of your connection function so it should be like this.

```
var connectWithRetry = function () {
    return mongoose.connect(url, options, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(
                "Failed to connect to mongo on startup - retrying in 5 sec\n\n",
                err
            );
            setTimeout(connectWithRetry, 5000);
        }
    });
};
mongoose.connection.once("open", () =>
    console.log(`Connected to mongo at ${url}`)
);

connectWithRetry();
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was, that i needed to start the mongoDB process manually. If you did not, start it an rerun it, for me that fixed the issue.

```
mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --fork
```